# Modify query string value using htacces

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

I want to redirect

`https://www.example.com/signup?plan=basic` to `https://www.example.com/signup?plan=basic-monthly` and `https://www.example.com/signup?plan=pro` to `https://www.example.com/signup?plan=pro-monthly` .

How can I achieve this using htaccess ?

There are many questions related to this here. But, couldn't find an answer for this specific scenario.

This is the code I tried and failed:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)plan=pro(&|$)
RewriteRule ^signup /$0?plan=pro-monthly [R=301,L]
```

Also, while trying the same with "basic" instead of "pro", the word "basic" i shown in red color as if it is a keyword.

Comment: Could you please share your htaccess rule file in your question what you tried, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Added

Comment: Your correct rule is correct. Can you post your full .htaccess in question?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, written with shown samples. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(plan=(?:basic|pro))$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(signup)/?$ $1?%1-monthly [L]
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Or you could try following too. Make sure you either put 1st solution rules OR this one at a time.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(signup)\?(plan=(?:basic|pro))\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1?%2-monthly [L]
```

Comment: @FathimaLinsaK, Hello Fathima, could you please do let me know on this one(willing to help here), thank you.